# Can't update document properties through any API - only through check out and check in

Tags: 2010, office-integration, updatelistitems, properties, metadata

I have a few documents in a library that I can't seem to update the properties for through the Web UI, the ListData.svc (JSON/JS), the object model or PowerShell. We have a property called Data Rights that I am trying to change from the string "Limited" to "Unlimited" - and I can see that a new version is created each time I invoke the update, yet the data is not saved.

The strange thing is, if I check out the document to my local SharePoint Drafts folder, open it in MS Word and modify the embedded server properties - then save/check in - the property is in fact updated correctly.

This impacts at least 20 or so known documents, but I am afraid it may be countless more - though certainly far from every document in this library. I would love to understand how to fix it (besides opening each doc in their respective office app and updating the server properties there). The logs in the 14 don't have any relevant information as to an error or something else stopping the update from happening.

Comment: And did you tried to checkout the file using Powershell or Object Model, make changes and checkout programaticallY?

Comment: I did not try checking it out using PowerShell or the Object Model because you can't usually modify the properties while a document is checked out.